# Multiple Monitors Separate Color Profiles?

Tags: color, color-management, windows-7

I have a huey color one and I can only color calibrate one monitor with one color profile.

How do you save different color profiles for each monitor?

My computer runs on Windows 7 and i use 2 monitors.

Comment: Yep, currently having the same issue. In Adobe Lightroom developing an image and on purpose one of the monitors is "darker"... When I made a screenshot on both previews (on each monitor) it had the one image darker.... [![This is the same image, but the previews on each monitor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YG1gg.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YG1gg.png) I think a bypass option should be implemented in Windows... :/

Answer (score 3):

You have to make the calibration program make a separate profile for each monitor. Depending on how the program works you either select the monitor in the program, or you might have to make the other monitor the main display to make the program profile it.

In Color Management in the control panel you can select which profiles are associated to which monitor. Your utility should then use that to determine which profile to use for each montior.